# Preg Match number

Tags: php

I want to ensure that when a user enters a number on an online form, he HAS to enter a number between 1 and 5, and no other number should be valid. If the user enters "6" for example, he will be met with a message such as "please enter a number between 1 and 5 only". Could someone please tell me how I can code this in PHP? What I can think of is

```
               if (empty($_POST["number"])) {
     $numberErr = "Number is required";
         } else {
     $number = test_input($_POST["number"]);
     // check if number is between 1 and 5 inclusive
     if (!preg_match("/^[1-5 ]*$/",$number)) {
       $number = "";
       $numberErr = "Only a number between 1 and 5 is allowed";

     }
   }
```

But this seems too simplistic and wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Should the user wirte only 1 character, or could it be any characters, between 1-5?

Comment: Simple: you convert to int and then check `if($num > 0 && $num < 6){}`

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[1-5]$/D",$number)) {
```

Without space and star and with a D modifier.

Your original pattern matched with the space as well and the * made it to match any length. (any means zero as well...)

The D is useful to avoid php's strange behaviour of not caring about trailing newline.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier,
>   a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is
>   a newline (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is
>   ignored if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier
>   in Perl.

Comment: I would also explain or at least quote from the manual what the `D` modifier does since it's not broadly used. +1 though